# Mongoose sort by exact value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So, I'm building a jobs site and on every job page I would like to show related jobs (Just like amazon shows you similar products on a product page)

My one idea of doing this is to do a query and find the objects with the most common fields.
But I have no idea if this can be done or if it is an idea in the first place

This is the schema(simplified)

```
const JobSchema = new Schema({
  location: String,
  name: String,
  specialization: String,
  fieldOfActivity: String,

});
```

And I want to query all the similar jobs by `name`, `location` and `specialization`

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough info here to answer your question. It might be helpful to include what your schema looks like and what the output you want with an example.
As you've put a value in the sort it sounds like what you actually want to do is `Job.find({location:"UK", fieldOfActivity:"Programming"})` to get all the relevant jobs in the UK.

Comment: i don't understand what you need, but maybe you need to sort by a calculated field. If you want this, you need to `$set` to add a temp-field with that caclculated value, and then sort by this field ($sort doesn't allow us to use expression as sort field). You can use aggregation for that with `$set` `$sort` and then `$unset` to remove the temp field.

Comment: Updated the question, hope it is more explicit now